# Pygame Basics not working

Tags: python, pygame

hello I am trying to learn Pygame for the new Boston and I am having a hard time geting the first leason to work it crashes every time I open it and I have tried eveything and I can't get it to work any help would be great

here is my code

```
bif = 'bg.jpg'
mif = 'ball.png'

import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((640,360),0,32)

background = pygame.image.load(bif).convert()
mouse_c = pygame.image.load(mif).convert_alpha()
while true:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT: 
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
    screen.blit(background, (0,0))
    x,y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    x -= mouse_c.get_width()/2
    y -= mouse_c.get_hight()/2
    screen.blit(mouse_c,(x,y))
    pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about spelling mistakes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fist of all the `true` in youre while loop needs to be `True` capitalized that will start your game loop

second `height` is spelt wrong

line 20 should be:

```
y -= mouse_c.get_height()/2
```

Then it should work perfectly

Comment: you sir are a life saver i need to pay attention more

Comment: haha no problem its kinda confusing at first i started out watching that exact tutorial bucky is awesome!